# jQuery DataTables - Get Column and Row after Filtering

Tags: datatables

I have the following function, which stores the row and column number of the cell that was clicked on in a data table. This works fine, UNLESS I filter out some rows by using the search box. How do I get the correct row and column after filtering?

```
        $('#myCoverageTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        sessionStorage["rowindex"] = tr.index();

        var td = $(this).closest("td");
        sessionStorage["colindex"] = td.index();
    });
```

My Fix:

```
        $('#myCoverageTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var table = $('#myCoverageTable').DataTable();
        sessionStorage["rowindexforstatus"] = table.row(this).index();
    });
```

Comment: You could use [cell().index()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().index()).  It will give you the Datatables row  index which is the order the data was populated, not the sorted order.  For example: `var cell = table.cell(this);`

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar, as noted above.